# Knockout Binding doesn't init, starts with update

Tags: javascript, data-binding, initialization, knockout.js

I have these two bindings that use the same init code, and are bound to the same value, but they don't init the same. The first behaves normally, the second one runs its update instead of init. Here are the bindings:

```
    function initToggle(element, valueAccessor) {
    // Initially set the element to be instantly visible/hidden depending on the value
    var value = valueAccessor();
    $(element).toggle(ko.utils.unwrapObservable(value)); // Use "unwrapObservable" so we can handle values that may or may not be observable
};

//Binding Handlers
ko.bindingHandlers.fadeVisible = {
    init: initToggle,
    update: function (element, valueAccessor) {
        // Whenever the value subsequently changes, slowly fade the element in or out
        var value = valueAccessor();
        ko.utils.unwrapObservable(value) ? $(element).fadeIn() : $(element).fadeOut();
    }
};

ko.bindingHandlers.slideVisibleVertical = {
    init: initToggle,
    update: function(element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor) {        
        var value = valueAccessor(); //Lastest binding value
        var allBindings = allBindingsAccessor(); //other bindings, allows options

        var valueUnwrapped = ko.utils.unwrapObservable(value); 
        var duration = allBindings.slideDuration || 400; // 400ms is default duration unless otherwise specified

        if (valueUnwrapped == true)
             $(element).show('slide', {direction: 'up'}, duration);
        else
            $(element).hide('slide', {direction: 'up'}, duration);
    }
};
```

Literally, same init function. Here is [a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tyrsius/EHgpM/4/) showing two buttons, both bound to the same value. `fadeVisible` starts out as shown, but `slidevisibleVertical` slides in. Both animate when updating. Anyone know whats going on here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `update` function always runs the first time as well.

For your `fadeVisible` the element will already be visible, so fading it in will not do anything.

For the other binding calling `slide` on it will still animate it, even though it is shown.

Some different ways that you could handle it:

- store something on the element ($data) to indicate that you are on the first pass and clear it as the end of the update (or vice-versa)
- check the visibility before sliding (as you mentioned in the comments)

Comment: Interesting, do you know if there are any plans to change this?

Comment: Also, you forgot one option, which I think might be easiest: check the visibility before sliding the element.

Comment: No, the `update` functionality is important and is intended to run even on the initial binding.  Generally, this will do the initial population of the value.  You certainly can check the visibility.  That sounds like a fine thing to do.  I did not have a chance to try your code.

Answer (score 1):

To clarify the accepted answer's comment about storing something on the element ($data), here is sample code:

```
ko.bindingHandlers.myHandler = {
    init: function (element, valueAccessor) {
        $(element).data("isFirstPass", true);
    },
    update: function (element, valueAccessor) {
        // Always unwrap so that ko tracks the dependency
        ko.unwrap(valueAccessor());

        if ($(element).data("isFirstPass")) {
            $(element).removeData("isFirstPass")
        }
        else {
            // Do something cool
        }
    }
};
```